# It is safe to copy the orientdb database files as backup mechanism

Tags: orientdb

I have highload on writes database. It's safe to copying files as backup mechanism, or better use export api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation

Backup does a consistent copy of database, all further write operations are locked waiting to finish it. The database is in read-only mode during backup operation. If you need an read/write database during backup setup a distributed cluster of nodes.

Export, instead, doesn't lock the database and allow concurrent writes during the export process. This means the exported database could have changes executed during the export.

I think that if you copy the folder of your database and your database have some problem that problem remains while with import and export it could be resolved.

Comment: Does it mean that the database can be corrupted during copying folder?

Comment: No, I meant if the db already have problems, copy the folder does not create problems.

Comment: So answer on my question "It's safe to copy the db folder during write workload" is "Yes"?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to copy the db folder during write workload